# Normal jquery Modal box close event in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am using normal modal box in angularjs. I mean model box opening code is

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#myModal" ng-click="getsingledataForUpdate(row.id)"></i>
```

Now what I want is I want to add a modal close event like this

```
$( '#myModal' )
        .on('hide', function() {
           console.log('hide');
        })
        .on('hidden', function(){
           console.log('hidden');
        })
        .on('show', function() {
           console.log('show');
        })
        .on('shown', function(){
          console.log('shown' )
        });
```

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: Use [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) instead of bootstrap component

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
   $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});

 //html
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

Best you can use angular bootstrap modal..
[Angular UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: I want to do some code changes on close of the modal box. This code opens the modal box but what i need is write some code on close of modal box.

Comment: I faced same kind of popup close issue in my project. Just clearly explain. What is your problem.?

Comment: I got solution  <br/> `$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {   
            $('video').trigger('pause');
        });` <br/>This one works fine. Thank you @Manikandan